# DataTable - How to create subcolumns

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable and I would like each of my columns to have the three same subcolumn :

```
       |       Column1      |     Column2        |      Column3        |
       | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat1 | cat2 | cat3  |
row1   |  2   |  3   |  1   |   1  |   2  |   0  |   2  |  1   |   0   |
row2   |  7   |  5   |  7   |   2  |   4  |   1  |   0  |  1   |   2   |
row3   |  3   |  0   |  3   |   3  |   8  |   0  |   2  |  0   |   2   |
```

How can I add such subcolumns ? The number of columns is determined at runtime but the number of subcolumns is known at compile time.

Comment: this (column groups or header rows with merged columns) is not a property of the `DataTable`, but a feature of a renderer (client-side control). Depends on the presentation format.

Comment: Are you asking for a pivot? So for every possible category you want the count per column? You should do that in the database(in MS-SQL there is a PIVOT operator).

Answer (score 3):

There is no feature "sub-column" in a `DataTable`. A table can only have columns(like a database table too). But i think you are confusing storage with display.

Store them with separate columns but group them together where you want to diplay it. Maybe your datamodel is wrong and you need another column for the category:

```
var tbl = new DataTable("Sample");
tbl.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
tbl.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(int));
tbl.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(int));
tbl.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(int)); // foreign-key to category table
```